# Python not printing all the sys.argv

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, sys

I'm getting a list out of range error from sys.argv[1] and I tried making a simple script with this code.

```
import sys
print sys.argv
```

I get this on cmd:

```
C:\...\...\...\py>back.py exampleargv
['C:\\...\\...\\...\\py\\back.py']
```

I don't know why I don't get the next arg.

Comment: Is that a typo. The script name is back.py but it prints backdoor.py?

Comment: This makes no sense. Your script is called `back.py` but the script outputs that its name is `backdoor.py`. Please post accurate code and results and then we can help.

Comment: Must be Windows specific. Works fine for me on OS X and Ubuntu :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a windows specific problem: try "python back.py examplearg" and it will work.

Solution (besides not running Windows!) is to update your registry.

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2010/12/14/problem-passing-arguments-to-python-scripts-on-windows/

Set these keys = value

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Applications\python26.exe\shell\open\command = "C:\Python26\python26.exe" "%1" %*

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\py_auto_file\shell\open\command = "C:\Python26\python26.exe" "%1" %*